# How do I permenantly delete a row of arrays and shift a row of arrays upwards?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, if-statement

I've been assigned by school to create an application that contains a book list with 20 different books in it and build a menu with following options:

(a) List – Display the list in tabular format. Each display should contain an appropriate heading and column captions;

(b) Search – Search for a book record in the list using the ISBN and print the full record for the book;

(c) Delete – Delete an existing book record from the list;

(d) Exit – Stop the program.

Here is the sample of my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    char code[50];
    char author[50];
    char name[50];
    char edition[50];
    char publish[50];
    char price[50];
} BOOK_LIST;

void list         (BOOK_LIST book[], int rows);
void showBook    (BOOK_LIST book[], int rows);
void updateRecord  (BOOK_LIST book[], int rows);
void advancedSearch (BOOK_LIST book[], int rows);
int deleteBook (BOOK_LIST book[], int rows);
int  searchBook(BOOK_LIST book[], int rows);

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile("list.txt");

if(!inFile)
    cout << "Error opening input file\n";
else
{

    BOOK_LIST books[50];
    int index = -1, choice;

    inFile.getline(books[++index].code, 50);
    while(inFile)
    {
        if(inFile.peek() == '\n')
            inFile.ignore(256, '\n');
        inFile.getline(books[index].author, 50);
        inFile.getline(books[index].name, 50);
        inFile.getline(books[index].edition, 50);
        inFile.getline(books[index].publish, 50);
        inFile >> books[index].price;

        // read next number
        inFile >> books[++index].code;
    }
    inFile.close();

    // menu starts
    do
    {
        cout << "Do you want to:\n";
        cout << "1. List all books\n";
        cout << "2. Get details about a book\n";
        cout << "3. Delete a book from the list\n";
        cout << "4. Exit\n";
        cout << "5. Advanced Search\n";
        cout << "Enter choice: ";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1 : list(books, index);
                     break;
            case 2 : showBook(books, index);
                     break;
            case 3 : updateRecord(books, index);
                     break;
            case 5 : advancedSearch(books, index);
            case 4 : break;

            default: cout << "Invalid choice\n";
        }
    } while (choice != 4);

    ofstream outFile("list.txt");
    if(!outFile)
        cout << "Error opening output file, records are not updated.\n";
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            outFile << books[i].code << endl;
            outFile << books[i].author << endl;
            outFile << books[i].name << endl;
            outFile << books[i].edition << endl;
            outFile << books[i].publish << endl;
            outFile << books[i].price << endl;
        }
        outFile.close();
    }
}
return 0;
}

void list(BOOK_LIST book[], int rows)
{
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    cout << "ISBN\t        Author          BookName        Edition\tPublisher\t Price\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        cout << book[i].code << "\t" << book[i].author << "\t"
             << book[i].name << "\t" << book[i].edition << "\t"
             << book[i].publish << "\t"
             << " " << book[i].price << endl;   
    return;
}

int searchBook(BOOK_LIST book[], int rows)
{
    int i = 0;
    bool found = false;
    char code[50];

cout << "Enter an ISBN code of a book to search: ";
fflush(stdin);
cin.getline(code, 50);

while (i < rows && !found)
{
    if (strcmp(code, book[i].code) == 0)
        found = true;
    else
        i++;
}
if (found)
    return i;
else
    return -1;
}

void showBook(BOOK_LIST book[], int rows)
{
int pos = searchBook(book, rows);
if (pos != -1)
{
    cout << "Author is " << book[pos].author << endl;
    cout << "Book name is "<< book[pos].name << endl;
    cout << book[pos].edition << " Edition" << endl;
    cout << "The publisher of this book is " << book[pos].publish <<  endl;
    cout << "Current price is " << book[pos].price << endl;
}
else
    cout << "Product not found\n";

return;
}

void updateRecord(BOOK_LIST book[], int rows)
{
int pos = deleteBook(book, rows);
char code [50];
int i,j = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < rows ; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(code, book[i].code))
        {
            strcpy(book[j].code , book[i].code);
            strcpy(book[j].author, book[i].author);
            strcpy(book[j].name, book[i].name);
            strcpy(book[j].edition, book[i].edition);
            strcpy(book[j].publish, book[i].publish);
            strcpy(book[j].price, book[i].price);

            j++;
        }//if
        else
        {
            i++;

        strcpy(book[j].code, book[i].code);
        strcpy(book[j].author, book[i].author);
        strcpy(book[j].name, book[i].name);
        strcpy(book[j].edition, book[i].edition);
        strcpy(book[j].publish, book[i].publish);
        strcpy(book[j].price, book[i].price);

        j++;

    }//else

}//for
return;
}

int deleteBook (BOOK_LIST book[], int rows)
{
int i = 0;
bool found = false;
char code[50];

cout << "Enter an ISBN code of a book to delete: ";
fflush(stdin);
cin.getline(code, 50);

while (i < rows && !found)
{
    if (strcmp(code, book[i].code) == 0)
        found = true;
    else
        i++;
}
if (found)
    return i;
else
    return -1;
}

void advancedSearch (BOOK_LIST book[], int rows)
{

char advanced[50];
cout << "Please enter either the author's name or the book name to search: ";
fflush(stdin);
cin.getline(advanced, 50);

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{

    if(strstr(book[i].author, advanced) || strstr(book[i].name, advanced))
    {
        cout << "ISBN is " << book[i].code << endl;
        cout << "Author is " << book[i].author << endl;
        cout << "Book name is " << book[i].name << endl;
        cout << book[i].edition << " Edition" << endl;
        cout << "Publisher is " << book[i].publish << endl;
        cout << "Current price is " << book[i].price << endl;
    }

}

return ;
}
```

The problem starts here:
When I want to permanently delete a whole row of book record. But the book record is still there after deleting.

First, this is my menu, then I press 1 to check the list for the IBSN. Then, I press 3 to proceed to the deleting part. At that time, I choose TheHost to delete. After the deleting, to ensure that I have deleted the chosen book, so I press 1 to check the list again, but unfortunately the book is still there:

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/planomxjuze9lul/Untitled2.png?dl=0]

If I am able to delete a book record, and how do I delete a record permanently? And after deleting a record, how do I move the remaining records upwards, so that it won't leave any empty row there?

The function for the deleting:

```
void updateRecord(BOOK_LIST book[], int rows)
    {
    int pos = deleteBook(book, rows);
    char code [50];
int i,j = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < rows ; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(code, book[i].code))
        {
            strcpy(book[j].code , book[i].code);
            strcpy(book[j].author, book[i].author);
            strcpy(book[j].name, book[i].name);
            strcpy(book[j].edition, book[i].edition);
            strcpy(book[j].publish, book[i].publish);
            strcpy(book[j].price, book[i].price);

            j++;
        }//if
        else
        {
            i++;

        strcpy(book[j].code, book[i].code);
        strcpy(book[j].author, book[i].author);
        strcpy(book[j].name, book[i].name);
        strcpy(book[j].edition, book[i].edition);
        strcpy(book[j].publish, book[i].publish);
        strcpy(book[j].price, book[i].price);

        j++;

    }//else

}//for
return;
}
```

[The Text file that I used in this program a.k.a the BOOK_LIST](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bo5zfiufl53ck7w/list.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Please try debugging.

Comment: Throw out those fixed and dynamic size arrays and replace `string` and `vector` would be the first thing I'd do.  But other than that, I do not see a point where you change the number of rows.  You need that: to erase, copy each element after the delete pos down 1, then shrink the number of rows by 1.  Also, split io/ui and business logic code into different functions.

Comment: You're trying to do several things at once. **Try something simpler first.** Try making an array of `int`, filling it with numbers, then removing one number and moving others to fill the gap. Once you have that working perfectly, this will be easy. And once you've solved that, you can concentrate on learning 1) [minimal complete examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), 2) [basic_string](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html) (much handier than `char[]`) and 3) writing a `Book` class and making a collection of *that*, rather than separate collections of all the things a book *is.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see (at least) two problems with your code around deleting a book.

1. in `update_record` you're using a `char code[50]` which is being used to compare with `strcmp` later on but is not initialized.
2. when you delete a book you should update your `index` which becomes `rows` in the `update_record` method. However `index` is passed to `rows` by value which means that even if you try running `--rows;` in `update_record` it won't decrement `index`. You'll need to pass it by reference for it to update `index`.

---

On a side note, I agree with comments regarding fixing your code to use `vectors`/`maps` & `strings` instead of simple arrays and `char*`.
But since you mentioned it was a school task I would guess you haven't reached that sort of material yet.

Good Luck.

Comment: thank you very much! Yes, it is a school task, pass or fail is all on this project.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment most probably expects you to use `std::list` template rather than the classical C array. Insertion and deletion is natural for lists.

An alternative would be to use `std:map` using the ISBN as a key. ISBN is supposed to be globally unique.

Comment: my teacher just taught me until how to input a text file..I don't know anything further than that...by the way, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on my comment, here is one way to remove an element from an array.

Suppose we have an array of `char` called **X**, containing {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}, and we want to get rid of 'c'.

If we want to maintain the order of the remaining elements, then what we're aiming for is {'a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f'}. So we *copy* the 'd' into the 'c' place, the 'e' into the old 'd' place, and so on:

```
a b c d e f
a b d d e f
a b d e e f
a b d e f f
```

We can do this with code like

```
for(int k=2; k<5; ++k)
  X[k] = X[k+1];
```

And what happens to that extra 'f' at the end? We could write some placeholder into that unwanted space, and then watch out for that placeholder for the rest of the run. Or, we could just *stop using that space,* and say that from now on we're considering an array of length 5. That extra 'f' will still be there, but for now we don't care about what exists past the end of our array.

(If we *don't* care about the order of the remaining elements, then we can make this a lot simpler.)

Remember, it's always easier to develop new functionality in isolation.

Once you have this working, you can apply it in your code and get a passing grade, but if you really want to learn something useful you should write a `Book` class.

Comment: Thank you very much for the guidance, appreciate the help.